# How to send email after registration using laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

I want to send an email notification after registration when the user will register they will get an email notification please help me how can send an email?

**UserController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{     
    $data = [
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name'         => $request->last_name,
        'name'              => $request->first_name . ' ' . $request->last_name,
        'email'             => $request->email,
        'password'          => bcrypt($request->password),
        'country_id'        => $request->country,
        'user_type'         => 'customer',
        'active_status'         => '1',
        'activation_code'   => str_random(30)
    ];
    
    $user_create = User::create($data);        
    Mail::to($request->email)->send(new UserSignUpMail);              
}
```

**UserSignUpMail**

```
 <?php
    class UserSignUpMail extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
        /**
         * Create a new message instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Build the message.
         *
         * @return $this
         */
        public function build()
        {
            return $this->markdown('emails.userSignUp');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 8 Send email example; In this tutorial, you will learn how to send email in laravel 8 using SMTP drivers like Mailgun, Postmark, Amazon SES, and sendmail.

after the registration you can call your function

This link will help you [Send Email](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-6-email-send-using-mailable-class-tutorial-example/)

Comment: It is quite correctly stated.

Answer (score 0):

what  email service are you using?
add credentials to that service in config/mail.php
or if its sendgrid we should use library provided by them

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait SendMail
{

protected function SendEmail($from_name, $to_email, $to_name, $subject, $body, $template)

{

try {


$from_email = 'sender@gmail.com';
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();

$email->setFrom($from_email, $from_name);

$email->setSubject($subject);

$email->addTo($to_email, $to_name);

$email->addContent("text/plain", $body);

$email->addContent("text/html", $template);

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('SENDGRID_API_KEY');

$response = $sendgrid->send($email);

return $response->statusCode();

} catch (Exception $e) {

return 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

}

}



//example

//$this->SendEmailWithAttachment("from_name", "xyz@xyz.com", "name", "Subject", "Body", "Template string", "URL, "file.mp3");

protected function SendEmailWithAttachment($from_name, $to_email, $to_name, $subject, $body, $template, $attachment_file_url, $file_name)

{

try {

$file_encoded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment_file_url));



$from_email = 'qwertyvate@gmail.com';

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();

$email->setFrom($from_email, $from_name);

$email->setSubject($subject);

$email->addTo($to_email, $to_name);

$email->addContent("text/plain", $body);

$email->addContent("text/html", $template);

$email->addAttachment(

$file_encoded,

null,

$file_name,

null

);



$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));



$response = $sendgrid->send($email);

return $response->statusCode();

} catch (Exception $e) {

return 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

customize sending email in `app/mail.php` or `.env` file.
You can use https://mailtrap.io/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have set the right Mailsettings in your .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=your.server.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=1234
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hi@mail.com
```

You can send Mail from Controller like that:

```
return \Mail::to("your@mail.com")        
->send(new UserSignUpMail());
```

or via route:

```
Route::get(“/send-email”, function() {
    return new UserSignUpMail();
});
```

In both cases you need the Laravel Mail Facade.
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;`

In your build() function in you **userSignUp** class then replace the:

`return $this->markdown('emails.userSignUp');`

with :

`$this->view('emails.userSignUp');`

And you sending "real" mails.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Generate Notification

```
php artisan make:notification WelcomeEmailNotification
```

Step 2: Setup RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->notify(new WelcomeEmailNotification());
        
    return $user;
}
```

Step 3: Setup WelcomeEmailNotification

```
use App\Models\User;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hello, '.$this->user->name)
                ->line('Welcome to Codelapan.')
                ->action('Explore', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

Step 4: Add Attachment (if you want)

```
    public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hello, '.$this->user->name)
                ->line('Welcome to Codelapan.')
                ->action('Explore', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!')
                ->attach('promotion.PNG');
}
```